# Setting Default map_shape_click input on leaflet map in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have an Rshiny application with a leaflet map and shapefile containing county borders of a given state. When the application is run, the map appears along with additional user input options above it. Once the map appears, there is a note telling the users to click on a county for detailed findings on that county. Once a county is selected, an observeEvent for map_shape_click is triggered which displays data tables below the map. I would like to set it up so that the data tables for a specific county are displayed as soon as the application is started by telling Rshiny to click on a county of my choice at the start of the application. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post sample code of your app so others can help. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.